# Item Query not returning results when search with custom field in Arabic language

Tags: sitecore-query

I am using Item Query to get featured Items using Isfeatured field in template, so my query like this:

```
+template:{A0ABC519-3848-4930-965A-90F9F1B7F319};custom:isfeatured|true;language:english
```

It is working correctly in the English language but in arabic language it is not returning featured data

```
+template:{A0ABC519-3848-4930-965A-90F9F1B7F319};custom:isfeatured|true;language:arabic_u.a.e.
```

If I removed this from the query `custom:isfeatured|true;`, it returns all the items in the Arabic language correctly.

Any Suggestions?

Comment: I think the . in the u.a.e might be messing up the query. Solr probably interprets it as something else

Comment: Are you using Solr or lucene?

Comment: As I see, you are using strange search query for language. Instead of  `language:english` should be `language:en`.

Comment: The Problem was in the language name "u.a.e." as it contain "." so it causes issue in query as when using any other language it works fine